# How to parameterize the search-locations path to be reusable in other config files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have different files (yml & xml files) where I'm hardcoding the same folder path containing my configuration files. I want to parameterize this path, so I can be able to move my configuration and modifying my parameter only once.

My `bootstrap.yml` :

```
...
      cloud:
        config:
          failFast: true     
          server:
            bootstrap: true
            prefix: /config
            native:
              search-locations: file:///C:/dev/workspace/application/config/{profile}
```

My `application-dev.yml` :

```
...
logging:
  config: file:///C:/dev/workspace/application/config/{profile}/log4j2-dev.xml
```

My integration-config.xml :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/dev/workspace/application/config/${spring.profiles.active}/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

How can I achieve that ? What's the best practice in this case ? Or is it even good practice to parameterize the search-locations path for the Spring Config Server File System ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First say I'm almost not use configuration file (yml properties xml...) directly in local-file-system(outside classpath) even for local test. And for `spring-cloud-config` what if you using remote location to contains config, question may different.
2. Second, did you using some project manager tool like `maven` or `gradle`? as `maven` is the default tool for spring-boot projects' build in my mind. And for maven there has plugin like [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to parameterize your config variable to `pom.xml` which can help you *modifying parameter only once* for all variable in one file in build step, and same as `gradle`.
3. For `spring-cloud-config`, it is possible to move your almost all configuration properties to it. Means that you can move your config properties from `application-dev.yml` and `integration-config.xml` to `spring-cloud-config`'s config file which in your case is `file:///C:/dev/workspace/application/config/{profile}` and it will load as env variables in runtime for spring autoconfigure or which you can `@Autowired` to your `Environment` what if you want get it manually.